# What Am I? -- A Little Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> The symbol,
>   a part.
>
> The node,
>   an object.
>
> One word.

Hints:

> Look out of your window and you will most probably find the answer (or at least a good hint).

*The riddle had been edited! The answer is still the same.*

Answer (score 1):

I relate a river with a bridge, an edge is a bridge if and only if it is not contained in any cycle.
It consists of specific symbols, e.g. G=(V,E) and is part of the theory. 
It is made up of points or nodes and model relations between objects.
So I guess it is a

> graph

Comment: Very nice idea, but not exactly what I had in my mind.
However, this was my first riddle -- so if it's to crazy, I could change it. :)
Do you want any hints or tips (that are really helpful)?

Comment: sure, any further hints are welcome!

Comment: I don't know if it's such a good hint, but you were on the right track somehow. "It" is also part of some special sort of a graph ...

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> USB logo?

```
The symbol,
a part.
```

> square, circle, triangle are symbols, part of the logo

```
The node,
an object.
```

> i suppose we can treat them as nodes?

```
One word.
```

> USB

Hint

> `Look out of your window and you will most probably find the answer (or at least a good hint).` window refers to Windows (computer), at the edge there's the logo!

Comment: "Window" does mean window, not Windows. So, look out. I wanted to give a hint about the relationship to nature ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about a

> Cloud

Reasoning:

The symbol,
a part

> Seems self explanatory to me - a symbol or picture of a cloud is always a part of the sky

The node, 
an object

> As in cloud computing!

Answer (score 0):

The first one:

> The river,
>
> a cycle

Sounds like

> Water - water in a river, the water cycle

But I'm not sure about the others yet...